# How to get position of a value in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
        $arr1 = preg_split("/[;]+/", $data);
        foreach ($arr1 as $arr1 => $value) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value;
            echo '</td>';
            if (key($value)==6)
            {
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

This is code I am using but the key function is not returning anything.
I want to get return the position of $value and want to excecute some code if it is divisible by 6.
How can I get the position of $value in $arr1?

Answer (score 2):

You must use a different variable than $arr1 to store the key.

Use this instead, where $key will be the key:

```
<?php
        $arr1 = preg_split("/[;]+/", $data);
        foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value;
            echo '</td>';
            if ($key==6)
            {
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can following example to get position of particular $value in array.

```
    <?php
     $value = 'green';
    $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

    $key_of_particular_value = array_search($value, array);

  //After perform above operation $key_of_particular_value = 2
  //Below statement will check whether key is divided by 6 or not
  if(($key_of_particular_value % 6) == 0)
  {
  //perform your operation
  }


?>
```

To know more please refer following link-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score -1):

You have used same variable $arr1 for key and original array, try using another variable to get key(index)

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
```